# JSch ChannelExec Speedup

Tags: ssh, putty, jsch

I am writing a JUnit integration test that communicates with a Linux server. I am using the JSch libraries to perform SSH, and SFTP. I noticed with PuTTY, initially connecting to the server with SSH takes about 20 - 25 seconds, but once I'm in, shell commands are really quick when entered. However, when I use a channelExec reference to perform a system command, it takes that same 20 - 25 seconds for every command that is executed. I would like the commands to be as quick as if I were inputting them in PuTTY. I noticed the program gets hung up when it is reading input from the channel. The JSch session is initialized before the tests are executed here...

```
    public void connectToServer() {
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(sUserName, sHostName, 22);
        session.setPassword(sPassword);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: Establishing SSH Connection...");
        session.connect();
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: SSH Connection established.");
        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: Creating SFTP Channel.");
        sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: SFTP Channel created.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The session is closed after all the tests are complete...

```
public void exit() {
    // Close SFTP Channel
    if(sftpChannel != null) {
        sftpChannel.disconnect();
        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: SFTP Channel closed.");
    }
    else {
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: No SFTP Channel to close.");            
    }

    // Close SSH resources
    if (session != null) {
        session.disconnect();
        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: SSH Disconnected.");
    }
    else {
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: No SSH Connection to close.");
    }

    // Close DB2 database resources
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
            if (DEBUG_MODE) println(
                    "UpdateProgram: Connection to DB2 database closed.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: No DB2 database connection to close.");
    }
}
```

Here is my test that calls the runCProgram() method that handles the ChannelExec instance...

```
public void effDateBeforeYesterday() {  
    String effDate = null,
           testRec = null;

    // Set effective date
    if(dateSize == 6)
        effDate = "000000";
    else 
        effDate = "00000000";

    // Upload Base test case and run C program
    program.setTransCount(5);
    program.put();
    program.runCProgram();

    // Upload test record   
    testRec = effDisDateInsert(effDate, currDate, true) + "\n";
    IO.fileWrite(testRec, file);
    program.setTransCount(1);
    program.put();
    program.runCProgram();

    // Query database for results

    // Clear table for next test

    assertTrue(true);
}
```

runCProgram() method:

```
    public void runCProgram() {
    String command = "cd " + updateProgramPath + " && " + "./" + updateProgram
            + " -tc -b. -ppackage -r20150601000000 -n" + transCount + " -d"
            + dbName + " -u" + dbUserName + " -w" + dbPassword + " -s"
            + scheduleName;
    ChannelExec channel = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        // Setup channel for system command execution
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: Exec channel created.");
        channel.setCommand(command);
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: Linux Command set to: " + command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        // Used for error detection in C program
        int temp = 0;

        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: Linux output: ");
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                if (in.available() > 0) continue;
                temp = channel.getExitStatus();
                if (temp != 0) throw new Exception(
                        "C Program Error, exit status " + temp);
                System.out.println("UpdateProgram: exit-status: " + temp);
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ee) {}
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        if (DEBUG_MODE) println("UpdateProgram: Exec channel closed.");
    }
```

It seems as though a new connection is being made for each command. Is there a way to speed up a ChannelExec reference so that it can execute system commands quickly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code executes only one command. How can we help you, if we do not know what do you do to execute the other commands?

Comment: Sorry for the bad code example. Here is my actual code.

Comment: We still cannot see, how and when you create the `session`.

Comment: Sorry again for not giving enough information. Let me know if this is still not enough.

Comment: Good. Thanks. Your code looks correct. Can you show us an event log from PuTTY? (right-click it's window caption and select *Event Log*)

Comment: Good to hear! So do you want me to show you the commands that I would run manually in PuTTY that I would like executed through the Java program? And then show you those results through PuTTY's event log?

Comment: It's more about determining when the delay happens. One would expect that the delay is when connection, but from the behavior of your code, it looks like the delay is when starting a shell. Hopefully the event log will show that.

Comment: Oh I see. How would I be able to track the JSch ChannelExec instance? Because that's what is used to initiate the remote system commands in my Java program, not PuTTY. I was just saying that I would like for the ChannelExec to keep a live session open like PuTTY does. It seems that I am only able to run commands at once during the ChannelExec's initialization. I'd like to run commands at different points in my program without having to wait for the ChannelExec to keep reconnecting. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: `ChannelExec` does not reconnect as long as you use the same `Session` for it. It just starts a new instance of shell over an existing connection. You first need to find what causes the delay (if the connection or the shell or something else) to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found a workaround to my problem. I used the shell channel instead of the exec, so that I could execute commands at any time during my program. Here is my code to start up the shell...

```
// Global variables
PrintStream shellInput;
PipedInputStream pin2;

private void connectShell() {
    PipedInputStream pin = null;
    PipedOutputStream pout = null;
    PipedOutputStream pout2 = null;
    String tmpStr = null;
    byte[] tmp = null;

    try {
        // Setup for channel I/O
        pin = new PipedInputStream();
        pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);
        pout2 = new PipedOutputStream();
        pin2 = new PipedInputStream(pout2);
        shellInput = new PrintStream(pout);

        // Create channel
        shellChannel = session.openChannel("shell");
        shellChannel.setInputStream(pin);
        shellChannel.setOutputStream(pout2);
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: Connecting to remote shell...");
        shellChannel.connect();

        // Block until shell is connected
        tmpStr = "";
        tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (!tmpStr.contains("Username String")) {
            while (pin2.available() > 0) {
                int i = pin2.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                tmpStr = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                if (i < 0) break;
                print(tmpStr);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            println("UpdateProgram: Connected to remote shell.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I use shellInput to send commands to the shell, and pin2 to read output from the shell. Thank you Martin Prikryl for your help!